# Non rectangular camera matrix

Tags: matrix, three.js, geometry

My project combines a projection screen with a head tracking device, where the screen should act as a window through which I could see my virtual "world". Basically, [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jd3-eiid-Uw).

Initially, I thought this would be easy: Map the camera position to the head tracking, have it point towards my window in the virtual world, adjust camera parameters to fit its frustum to the window, and voilà!

Except it doesn't work because I'm viewing the window (both real and virtual) at an angle, so the regular perspective camera doesn't do the trick: If I understand correctly, that camera 'input' is always rectangular, but I need to 'fit' it in a trapezoïd instead.

I think I should be able to achieve that by making my own projection matrix, but I'm a bit lost on how to do that: I have played a bit with basic matrix transforms (translate, scale, rotate), but I have zero experience with more complex stuff (ie perspective).

My best guess for now is trying to deduce the projection matrix from known transformed points (the corners of my window => the corners of the screen) but I feel like it's going to be quite expensive to do that each frame, and that doesn't account for the perspective inside the "window".

thanks for any help!

Comment: You need to use projection matrix with focal point specified (center of projection) in it  see [Projection matrices](http://info.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Teaching/Courses/eem.cgi/lectures_pdf/lecture3.pdf)